# How to include theme header and footer in taxonomy page which is inside in a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

`get_template_part( 'header' );`

`get_template_part( 'footer' );`

I including header & footer but i get blank page. So how i include header and footer of theme in taxonomy page inside a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php get_footer();?>
```